# Git detect squash and merged branches

Tags: git, version-control

I want to know if there is a way to detect if a squashed (on remote after approving a pull request) branch is merged into develop. Usually, I use

```
git branch --merged
```

However, this seems not to work due to squashing.

Comment: And this is (one reason) why I'm not a fan of squashing. It also allows you to lose filename changes when content is also changed. Bad practice IMO and shouldn't be allowed in normal team workflows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that there's no general yet reliable way to tell.

In many specific cases, it's easy to tell by comparing the *contents* of the new commit added to the upstream repository to the *contents* of the merge you proposed.  That is, in *your* repository—and/or on the clone you control on GitHub, if you and they did the merge through GitHub—you have:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/somebranch, upstream/somebranch
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature/yours
```

*They* used "squash and merge" to combine your three commits `I`, `J`, and `K` into one big `IJK` commit, which they added after commit `H`, so that *their* repository now reads:

```
...--G--H--IJK   <-- somebranch
```

The contents—as in, the associated *snapshot*—of commit `IJK` exactly match the contents (snapshot) of your commit `K`, and the log message of commit `IJK` is something that tells you that they squash-merged `feature/yours`.  So you now know that it is safe to resynchronize with them and delete `feature/yours`, using `IJK` instead.

However, if they added `IJK` after some other commit `L`, they now have:

```
...--G--H--L--IJK   <-- somebranch
```

In this case, the snapshot for commit `IJK` matches what you would get if you cherry-picked their `L`, or merged your `feature/yours` with their `upstream/somebranch` after fetching.  Discovering *this* is more difficult.  It could be automated for many cases, but there's no clicky button on GitHub to do so, for instance.  Furthermore, such automation would fail *if* they had to *modify* your work to make their `IJK`—though luckily (?) for you most upstreams just won't do that, forcing you to adapt your `I-J-K` sequence yourself by rebasing or merging anyway. :-)  In that case we are back to the earlier situation, where your adapted branch tip commit matches the one they make with their squash-merge operation.

As [Joe Phillips says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225918/git-detect-squash-and-merged-branches#comment97186594_55225918), the whole practice of squashing like this is somewhat dubious.  I would not go so far as to say it should *never* be used, but I would say that it should be rare rather than the norm in most situations.

Comment: So when I see this in the git commits in the web ui (enterprise, but same for github I imagine):

`user1 authored and user2 committed 21 days ago`

Is that 100% evidence that they squashed and that there are commits from either user1 or user2 that are lost / rewritten from the squash? Tested and I can get both author.name and committer.name with Octokit so wondering if this is one way of determining whether it came from a branch where there was a squash commit. @torek

Comment: @JohnZaj: The "X authored, Y committed" state is not guaranteed to mean "did a squash"—you may get the same for "rebase, then merge" operations, as well as for other cases that don't occur on these kinds of web interfaces but could happen via command line—but it's a pretty strong indicator. That particular state occurs when the author line in the commit differs from the committer line in the commit.